# bash script do not read last piped file

Tags: bash

```
for i in {1..255} ; do host 10.1.9.$i ; done |grep not|awk '{print $2}' | awk -F. '{print $1}'> /tmp/filx   | for i in `cat /tmp/filx` ; do echo $i ; done
```

Not sure why the o/p is not showing, the file do have values of un-used ips, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's almost never a good reason to pipe `grep` into `awk`.  `awk` can do pattern matching by itself - try `awk '/not/ {print $2}'` instead.

And piping awk into another awk is also unnecessary.  Here you just need to give it a set of field separators (space and `.`) instead of the default whitespace as separator:

```
awk -F'[ .]' '/not/ {print $2}'
```

A `for` loop around `cat` just to `echo` the contents of each line is similarly pointless.  Actually, worse than pointless - it's slow, inefficient, and subjects each line to standard shell word-splitting (not a problem with this particular input, but potentially a problem if you think this is a good technique and use it on input files where lines may contain spaces etc).  Just use `cat`.

But you don't even need to use `cat` here.  `tee` copies stdin to both a file and to stdout - i.e. it's like a fancy version of `cat` that also copies its input to a file.

Using `tee` as mentioned in [αғsнιη's answer](/a/385789/72456), your entire one-liner can be reduced to:

```
for i in {1..255} ; do "host 10.1.9.$i" ; done | 
    awk -F'[ .]' '/not/ {print $2}' | 
    tee /tmp/flix
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are redirected it to a file only. if you want pass it to the next command use `tee` to do both.

```
...  | tee /tmp/filx |...
```

The `tee` is used to write to the file and pass the stdout to the next command via `|` to read from stdin.

Or you should change your in this part of command `/tmp/filx   |`, the `|` to `;` or `&&` instead.